# obtaining record id after double clicking DataGridvView row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, event-handling

Is there any other concise way to get the record id from a DataGridView row double click event? Is that the event to use?

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var databaseRecordId = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
        //...
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be precise

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var databaseRecordId = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
    }
```

`CellDoubleClick` event better suits than `CellContentDoubleClick` or `CellMouseDoubleClick`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is necessarily "easier" but it would be a bit safer in case you don't want to display the id or change the column order in the gridview..

```
var databaseRecordId = ((MyBoundObjectType)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).MyRecordId;
```

Where `MyBoundObjectType` and `MyRecordId` are the type that is bound to the row and corresponding Id property.